# Backbone model getting over-ridden after initializing backbone relation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have a JSON response of an account based on which I'm creating **ModelA** which will be logged in user.

JSON response as id, emailid, trackingid, gender, customurl, mobile, picture_url and plan id.

Also I have a JSON response of post on which I am creating **ModelB**, JSON response as id, text,description, owner{id, customurl and picture url}.

My ModelA as this relation

```
relations : [
  {
    type : Backbone.HasMany,
    key : 'posts',
    relatedModel : PostModel,
    collectionType : AccountPosts,
    reverseRelation : {
      type : Backbone.HasOne,
      key : 'account',
      keySource : 'owner',
      includeInJSON : false
    }
  }
]
```

I create a instance of ModelA

```
currentUser = new ModelA()
```

and instance of post

```
post = new ModelB()
```

The problem is when the current user and post owner are the same, **currentUser** attributes are changed i.e emailid and other attributes which is not present in post owner are getting deleted.

I am guessing backbone creates a reference of each model internally and since the model id is same the second is over-riding the first.

If my guess is right how can I avoid the currentUser object getting overridden and if wrong what is the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Backbone Relational **reverseRelation** it creates a **bidirectional** relationship with a Model and its relatedModel. If you look at the [Examples](http://backbonerelational.org/#examples) on the Backbone Relational page they give an example of using a reverseRelation between a Person and a House via livesIn key. When you update either side of the relationship its going to update both sides of the relationship.

In your example when you add a post because there is bidirectional relationship with a UserModel and a Post, specifying an "owner" will cause an existing UserModel (currentUser) to also be updated. What you would gain is that a currentUser posts would also reflect the correct posts anytime you add a new Post to your AccountPosts collection which I'm assuming you would want.

So that you keep the reverseRelation in place, if you only want to see specific User attributes in the posts information you could specify those in the includeInJSON property.

Example is at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottluskcis/uNu7d/)

```javascript
// ModelB
var PostModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    defaults: {
        'id': '',
        'text': '',
        'description': '',
        'account': null
    } 
}); 

// collection of ModelB
var AccountPosts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PostModel 
});  

// ModelA 
var UserModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    defaults: {  
        'id': '',
        'customurl': '',
        'pictureurl': '', 
        'emailid': '',
        'trackingid': '',
        'gender': '', 
        'mobile': '', 
        'planid': '', 
        'posts': null 
    },

    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasMany,
            key: 'posts',
            relatedModel: PostModel,
            collectionType: AccountPosts,
            reverseRelation : { 
                key : 'account',
                includeInJSON: ['id', 'customurl', 'pictureurl']
            }  
        }
    ]
}); 

// json object returned from server request 
var accountJSON = {
    id: 1, emailid: 22222, trackingid: 3333, gender: 'M',
    customurl: 'www.myurl.com', mobile: '222-222-2222',
    pictureurl: 'www.mypic.com', planid: 444
}; 

var currentUser = new UserModel(accountJSON);  

// json object from server for posts
var postJSON = {
    id: 1, text: 'My First Post', description: 'A Post',
    account: { id: 1, customurl: 'www.myurl.com',
            pictureurl: 'www.mypic.com'}
};  

// example of just one post
var post = new PostModel(postJSON);
```

This JSON is the result

```json
CURRENT USER JSON
{"id":1,"emailid":22222,"trackingid":3333,"gender":"M","customurl":"www.myurl.com","mobile":"222-222-2222","pictureurl":"www.mypic.com","planid":444,"posts":[{"id":1,"text":"My First Post","description":"A Post","account":{"id":1,"customurl":"www.myurl.com","pictureurl":"www.mypic.com"}}]}

POST JSON
{"id":1,"text":"My First Post","description":"A Post","account":{"id":1,"customurl":"www.myurl.com","pictureurl":"www.mypic.com"}}
```